# How to solve __array_function__ internals source error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, neural-network

I'have a problem and can't figure out where the bug is.
While running mt script I get as error :

> Could not load source '<**array_function** internals>': Source
>   unavailable.

The point of my script is to desing an neural network form scratch given a specific architecure (2 Hidden Layers).

Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as random
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,classification_report
from sklearn import tree, datasets
from datetime import datetime

def architecture_nn(architecture):
    NN_array = []
    bias = []
    weights = []
    for index in range(0,len(architecture)):
        layer = list(0 for i in range(0, architecture[index]))
        NN_array.append(layer)

        if index !=0 and index != len(architecture):
            bias.append(list(random.random() for i in range(0,architecture[index])))
        if index != len(architecture)-1:
            weights_layer_tempo = np.zeros( (architecture[index],architecture[index+1]) , dtype=float)

            for i in range(0,architecture[index]):
                for j in range(0,architecture[index+1]):
                    weights_layer_tempo[i][j] = random.uniform(0.1, 100)

            weights.append(weights_layer_tempo)

    return NN_array,bias,weights

""" Forward porpagation """

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def tanh(x):
    return np.tanh(x)

def single_layer_forward_propagation(Layer1, Layer2, weights,inter_bias, activation):
    if activation is "tanh":
        activation_func = tanh
    elif activation is "sigmoid":
        activation_func = sigmoid 
    for i in range(0,len(Layer2)):
        for row in range(0,len(Layer1)) :
            Layer2[i] += Layer1[row]*weights[row][i]
        Layer2[i] = activation_func=(Layer2[i] + inter_bias[i])
    return Layer2

def full_forward_propagation(architecture,X,activation,NN_Array,weights,bias):
    #Initialisation des Inputs
    NN_Array[1] = X

    #Inputs vers HL1
    for layer in range(len(architecture)-1):
        NN_Array[layer+1] = single_layer_forward_propagation(NN_Array[layer],NN_Array[layer+1],weights[layer],bias[layer],activation)
    return NN_Array[3]

""" Backward propagation"""

def erreur(Y_pred,Y_real):
    erreur=list([0.0] for i in range(nb_output))
    for i in range(4):
        erreur[i] = (Y_pred[i]-Y_real[i])*(Y_pred[i]*(1-Y_pred[i]))
    return erreur

def hidden_erreur(weights,neuron,past_error,nb_perceptrons):
    erreur = list([0.0] for i in range(nb_output))
    for i in range(len(erreur)):
        erreur[i]=(neuron[i])*(1-neuron[i])*np.dot(weights[i],past_error)
    return erreur

def back_weights(weights,erreur,valeur_perceptron,learning_rate):
     for i in range(len(weights)):
        for j in range(len(weights[i])):
            weights[i][j] = weights[i][j] - learning_rate* erreur[j] *valeur_perceptron[i]
     return weights

def back_bias(bias,erreur,learning_rate):
    for i in range(len(bias)):
        bias[i]= bias[i] - learning_rate * erreur[i] * 1
    return bias

def full_backward_propagation(NN_Array,bias,weights,architecture,learning_rate,Y_real):
    erreur_map = [list([0.0] for k in range(len(NN_Array[3]))), 
                  list([0.0] for k in range(len(NN_Array[2]))),
                  list([0.0] for k in range(len(NN_Array[1])))]
    erreur_map[0] = erreur(NN_Array[3],Y_real)
    for n in range(-1,1,1):
        n=-n
        erreur_map[n]=hidden_erreur(weights[n],NN_Array[n],erreur_map[n-1],architecture[n])
    for k in range(-2,1,1):
        k=-k
        weights[k] = back_weights(weights[k],erreur_map[2-k],NN_Array[k],learning_rate)
        bias[k] = back_bias(bias[k],erreur_map[2-k],learning_rate)
    return bias,weights
def error_pred(Y_hat,Y_real):
    result=0
    for l in range(len(Y_hat)):
        if Y_hat[l] == Y_real[l]:
            result += 25
    return result

def train(X_train, Y_train,learning_rate,max_iter,architecture,activation):
    NN_Array,bias,weights = architecture_nn(architecture)
    Y_pred=[]
    Error_score=[]
    instances=[]
    for row_df in range(len(X_train)):
        instances.append(row_df)
        X = X_train.iloc[row_df,:]
        Y_real = Y_train[row_df]
        for iteration in range(max_iter):
            Y_pred.append(full_forward_propagation(architecture,X,activation,NN_Array,weights,bias))
            bias,weights = full_backward_propagation(NN_Array,bias,weights,architecture,learning_rate,Y_real)
    return NN_Array,weights,bias,Error_score,instances

def use_model(X,architecture,activation,NN_array,weights,bias):
    Sortie = []
    for u in range(len(X)):
        X_pp = X.iloc[u,:]
        Sortie.append(full_forward_propagation(architecture,X_pp,activation,NN_array,weights,bias))
    return Sortie
""" Training effectif"""

"""Lecture du fichier et préparation des data"""
df = pd.read_csv("sensor_readings_4.csv", usecols=[0,1,2,3,4], names=['Sensor1', 'Sensor2', 'Sensor3','Sensor4','Action']) #A modifier en cas de 24 entrées
Y_raw = df.pop('Action')

#Converting the action into binary set
Y_sharp=[]
for i in range(len(Y_raw)):
    if Y_raw[i] == "Move-Forward":
        sortie = [1,0,0,0]
    elif Y_raw[i] == "Slight-Right-Turn" :
        sortie = [0,1,0,0]
    elif Y_raw[i] == "Sharp-Right-Turn":
        sortie = [0,0,1,0]
    elif Y_raw[i]=="Slight-Left-Turn":
        sortie=[0,0,0,1]
    Y_sharp.append(sortie)


X = df
y = Y_sharp


##Splitting Training/Testing set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y_sharp, test_size = 0.20)


"""Initialisation du Neural Network"""
nb_input = 4
nb_neurons_HL1 = 5
nb_neurons_HL2 = 5
nb_output = 4
architecture = [nb_input , nb_neurons_HL1 , nb_neurons_HL2 , nb_output]
activation = "sigmoid"
learning_rate = 0.2
max_iter=10

""" Training et utilisation du modèle """

NN_Array,weights,bias,Error_score,instances = train(X_train, y_train,learning_rate,max_iter,architecture,activation)

"""Learning curve"""

lenght_df = len(X_train)
step_Learning_curve = int(np.floor(lenght_df/1000))
compteur=step_Learning_curve
Error_train = []
Instances_train =[]
while compteur <= lenght_df :
    X_prime = X_train.iloc[0:compteur,:]
    Y_prime_real = y_train.iloc[0:compteur,:]
    Y_prime_pred = []
    Y_prime_pred = use_model(X_prime,architecture,activation,NN_Array,weights,bias)
    Accuracy = accuracy_score(Y_prime_pred,Y_prime_real)
    error = 1-Accuracy
    Error_train.append(error)
    Instances_train.append(compteur)
    compteur += step_Learning_curve



plt.plot(Instances_train,Error_train,label='Training')
plt.xlabel('Instances')
plt.ylabel('Erreur')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Here is what's inside launch.json :

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python : Fichier actuel",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
        {
            "name": "Python: Debug Console",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "internalConsole"
            "debugStdLib": true
       }
    ]
}
```

I'm using VSCode 1.40, Python 3.7.4

Thanks for your attention !

Comment: You are missing a comma in your launch.json

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# case 1, error here
# x = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(loc=-2,scale=.5,size=500)),(np.random.normal(loc=2, scale=.5, size=500)))

# case 2, no error here
x = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(loc=-2, scale=.5,size=500), 
                    np.random.normal(loc=2, scale=.5, size=500)))
# plt.hist(x, normed = True)
# plt.xlim([-5,5])
# plt.show()
```

Looking at my example, you can find there is an **extra ")"**, which is the place your error comes out.

So looking at your code here:

```
erreur_map = [list([0.0] for k in range(len(NN_Array[3]))), 
                  list([0.0] for k in range(len(NN_Array[2]))),
                  list([0.0] for k in range(len(NN_Array[1])))]
```

**Delete the additional ")"**. Hope that can help you.